# How to upgrade sudo from 1.8.19p1-1 to 1.8.19p1-2 on debian Stretch to avoid the " Potential overwrite of arbitrary files" flaw?

Tags: debian, security, sudo, selinux, software-updates

I have the `sudo 1.8.19p1-1` installed on debian Stretch. I need to install the `1.8.19p1-2` to avoid the  [Potential overwrite of arbitrary files](https://www.sudo.ws/alerts/linux_tty.html) flaw.

```
Package  Type   Release     Fixed Version     Urgency   Origin  Debian Bugs
sudo    source  (unstable)  1.8.20p1-1                  863731
sudo    source  jessie      1.8.10p3-1+deb8u4           DSA-3867-1  
sudo    source  stretch     1.8.19p1-2          
sudo    source  wheezy      1.8.5p2-1+nmu3+deb7u3       DLA-970-1
```

The latest version of sudo is marked as fixed but it is not available through `apt`. ([security tracker debian](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-1000367))

```
# apt-cache policy sudo
sudo:
  Installed: 1.8.19p1-1
  Candidate: 1.8.19p1-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.8.19p1-1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

My `sources.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

[I have `selinux` installed on my system.](http://opensourceforu.com/2017/06/linux-distros-patch-highly-severe-sudo-vulnerability/)

How to install the `sudo 1.8.19p1-2` on debian Stretch?

Comment: You could just download the deb file and do `dpkg -i debfile`. It's currently available from incoming - http://incoming.debian.org/debian-buildd/pool/main/s/sudo/

Comment: This only afects you if you have SELinux enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just download the deb file and do `dpkg -i debfile`. It's currently available from incoming.debian.org: https://incoming.debian.org/debian-buildd/pool/main/s/sudo/.